# How to change the outlet of the TableViewcell when table is reloaded

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5.1

Im making anApp which has a address which has a listing page and a detail page .

[image: LISTING PAGE OF TH ADDRESS BOOK]

[image: DETAIL PAGE OF THE ADRESSBOOK]

If i click on email address of the detail page , it pops to the listing page. i want to show a tick on the listing page whose email is selected.(like shown below). The cell has a image (tick)

[image]

.I want change the outlet of the image in the cell when the lising page is reloaded. The cellforrowatindexapath is obiously not called when table is reloaded.Is there any way that i can get the index path of the cell .so that i can change the outlet of the cell when table is reloaded.Thank you....

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath should be getting called if you're doing [tableView reloadData].

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is not when we alloc the table.I got some memory issue when i dint alloc the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the accessory view type?
Set the `accessoryViewType` property on `UITableViewCell` to one of:

```
UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator
UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton
UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark    // you want this one
```

The default value is `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`.

You may have to called `[tableView reloadData]` when appropriate to reload the table data.

There are lots of questions on SO relating to accessory views, e.g. custom accessory views: [Using a custom image for a UITableViewCell's accessoryView and having it respond to UITableViewDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869421/using-a-custom-image-for-a-uitableviewcells-accessoryview-and-having-it-respond) for example.