# Need to make added button in custom cell in IOS behave as an accessory button

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, custom-cell, accessory

In Swift, I have created a custom cell with 3 labels and in which I have added a button or type UIButton. The button is displayed in each row of the table. When I click on the button I would like to save the indexPath of the row in which the button was pressed so I can replace the labels with different text. It is unclear to me how I could proceed. I would like to call the accessory button method (accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath) if possible.

Thank you  for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is in cellForRowAtIndexPath, set the tag of the UIButton for that cell equal to the indexPath.row.  When the button is tapped, it can trigger

```
- (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIButton *) sender{
    int rowNum = sender.tag;
}
```

So now you have the rowNum of the button that was tapped.  Not sure what you want to do with it though...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have pretty much answered you own question but the trick is to set the button as an accessory view. For this accessory view, use a selector; e.g. `didClickAccessoryView` and then eventually call `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` from there.

Here's an objective-c implementation for the same:

[Using a custom image for a UITableViewCell's accessoryView and having it respond to UITableViewDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869421/using-a-custom-image-for-a-uitableviewcells-accessoryview-and-having-it-respond)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Here is what I tried:     

@IBAction func showSubcategoryEditor(sender: UIButton) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(sender.frame) as NSIndexPath {
            tableView.delegate.accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath(indexPath)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            savedRow = indexPath.row
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SubcategorySegue", sender: self)
    }
However I get the follwoing error message:

Comment: (UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'indexPathForRowAtPoint