# Where to find a pause styled disclosure button for iOS audio application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

So I've been hitting my head for awhile now, trying to dig up the correct Apple styled icon.  It's not listed in the standard provided icons.  Does anyone know how to get access to it without having to build it from scratch in photoshop?

Here's the image:

[image: pause style disclosure]

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no accessory style for this. However, you don't need to build it from scratch in Photoshop. You just linked it to this post. Save that image, add the PNG to your project. When setting up your cells, create a new UIImageView, load the image from your project, and then sett the UIImageView as your cell's accessoryView.

There's some example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403748/how-can-i-customize-the-accessory-disclosure-image-in-a-uitableviewcell/403796#403796).

Comment: Hi Nathanial ... thanks for taking time to answer my question.  I guess my big concern is the resolution.  I haven't determined actual size I need it at, but I figured I would need a larger version of it for the retina display.  I was hoping there was some ready-baked version of it, but I guess I can always go with what I have.