# Adding a picture on the TableView Cell when a button is pressed

Tags: uitableview

think about a true false application. the app has two buttons on the bottom of the screen     (TRUE/FALSE) and an array of questions/problems in the mainView. i want to show a checkmark or a cross based on the response from the user on the right of that particular cell.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell has a property called 'accessoryView' that can be used to control a view that appears on the right size of the cell.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *accessoryView
```

You could create a UIImageView with your checkmark or cross image and use it to set this property.

There an example here in this prior question: [How can I customize the accessory disclosure image in a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403748/how-can-i-customize-the-accessory-disclosure-image-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. i have another quick question. where do i store the data ( problems/questions)? and how can i make the data to appear in a random order? sorry i am new to the iOS dev and have a few things that are unclear. thanks

Comment: Your follow ups are definitely beyond the scope of this question.  If you need help with those parts I suggest opening up separate question(s) here at SO and someone can answer those topics.  To get you started though, for storing data look into Apple's Core Data framework for iOS.