# I saw double chevron in my disclosure indicator. Why and how to fix this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

[image]

The distance between chevron is affected by the width of UITableViewCell. If it's less than 320 it'll be even bigger.

I deliberately make the background of my contentView to be green for clarity.

Setting the background of UITableViewCell will make the cell unseenable.

Only the first chevron turn into a move cell sign when table is in edit mode.

[image]

Note: All of my UITableViewCell class is created with a special technique. Basically I load an xib with a UITableViewCell, and then the cell I want to create absorb the property of that UITableViewCell

Here is the full code:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        //[self vLoadMainBundle];
        //self=(BGBaseTableViewCell *)self.view;
        [self BaseInitialize];
    }
    return self;

}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self BaseInitialize];
        //[self vLoadMainBundle];
        //self=(BGBaseTableViewCell *)self.view;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) vLoadMainBundle
{
    if ([self class] == [BGBaseTableViewCell class])
    {
        return;
    }

    NSString * className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];
}
-(void) vAfterLoadMainBundle
{
    //self=self.view;

    self.contentView.frame =self.view.contentView.frame;
    self.frame=self.view.frame;
    //self.contentView.frame=self.contentView.frame;

    [self.contentView kidnapChildrenAndAttributes:self.view.contentView];
    [self kidnapChildrenAndAttributes:self.view];
    self.editingAccessoryType= self.view.editingAccessoryType;
    self.accessoryType = self.view.accessoryType;
    self.selectionStyle =self.view.selectionStyle;

    //PO1(@(self.editingAccessoryType));
    //PO1(@(self.accessoryType));
    //PO1(@(self.selectionStyle));
    while (false);

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    //self.view=nil;
    PO(self.view);
    PO(self.view.subviews);
    self.view.hidden=true;
    [self furtherCustomInitializer];
}
-(void)BaseInitialize
{
    [self vLoadMainBundle];
    [self vAfterLoadMainBundle];
}
```

Works perfectly fine on iOS 6

It has come to my attention that the original view where I draw stuffs are still being drawn. Hence,

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find anything in the reference but I assume this is just how the accessory view is intended to work on iOS 7.
You can work around this by providing a custom image to be displayed in the accessory view. Like so:

```
myCell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] 
                   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Something" ]];
```

This also described here: [How can I customize the accessory disclosure image in a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403748/how-can-i-customize-the-accessory-disclosure-image-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Are you sure? I thought accessories view is a single chevron?

Comment: @JimThio well I cannot proof it. But you said it depends on the size of the cell. I mean if there is a lot of space on the right, the chevron might grow bigger. Can't you just adjust your cell size to always have the same right-edge spacing so the chevron appears normal. In my Apps the chevron lies in or above the cell. My cells are full width and the chevron appears inside the cell.

Comment: The way my code create the UITableViewCell was the problem.